# bash script with if [[ ! -f path_to_files ]]

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

On MacOS Catalina, I have a bash script with

```
if [[ ! -f $CR/home/files/Recovery_*.txt ]]
then
  echo "File does not exists in /home/files directory. Exiting" >> $log
  echo "Aborted - $CR/home/files/Recovery_*txt not exist"
  exit
fi
```

Even though there are 2 files in the directory the script exits. If I list directory contents beforehand there are 2 files. If I change it as follows the if is skipped:

```
if [[ `ls -la $CR/home/files/Recovery_*.txt | wc -l` -eq 0 ]]
then
  echo "No files are :"
  exit
fi
```

I am wanting to use the if -f conditional.

Any suggestions please?

Cheers, C

Comment: I pasted your code into shellcheck.net and found that "-f doesn't work with globs"

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) suggests [using a loop](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2144) since `[[ -f .. ]]` doesn't work with globs

Answer (score 1):

If you use `nullglob`, a glob expression that doesn't match returns an empty string. This lets us count files in bash without spawning other processes. Create an array with the expression, then check its length.

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=($CR/home/files/Recovery_*.txt)
if [[ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo "No files"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: I'd maybe redirect your error message to stderr and exit with a nonzero status (just `exit` alone does the right thing if it's what you run immediately after a command that returned an error, but that's not the case here, since we don't expect `echo` to fail).

Comment: I agree. Was focusing on the condition and just copied OP's original then clause.

Answer (score 0):

[Edited]
The error was not the variables, but the missing shebang as the script has come across from W2K3 SFU.

The tip about shellchecker.net was awesome and I will use that from now.

Thanks.